# Crawl Emails from specific pages of a given list of urls

Tags: python, email, scrapy

I have a list of urls in a txt file and then a list of contact_page_patterns. I need to check only those specific pages to crawl the emails of the url.

Kindly suggest me some possibilities how I can do. I am new to Python and Scrapy. Thank you in Advance.

```
   class FinalspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
       name = "finalspider"
       source_urls = open("/Users/NiveRam/Documents/urllist.txt","rb")
       start_urls = [url.strip() for url in source_urls.readlines()]
       contact_page_pattern = ['help','office','global','feedback','branch','contact','about']

       def parse(self, response):
           hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
           emails = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', response.body)
           story = FinaltestItem()
           story["url"] = response.url
           story["title"] = response.xpath("//title/text()").extract()
           story["email"] = emails
           return(story)
```

This retrieves the emails form the whole body of the webpage and outputs emails like

emails:[info@abc.com,infor@abc.com, yourname@abc.com]

Comment: You're a spammer, right?

Comment: I seriously need to learn this on website crawling. I'm not a spammer

Comment: Your email regex is not very accurate.  It will miss `firstname_lastname+stuff@example.com` and erroneously extract pretty much anything with an `@` in it.  If you do some post-filtering, the false matches might be easy to filter out.  Conventional wisdom is don't use regex (alone) for this.

Comment: Sorry, I just referred some previous suggestions and comments and used them. So you suggest me to try some other regrex on this ?

Comment: A better regex will get you the matches you missed but it's hard to keep out the false positives with regex alone.  Whether that's a problem depends on what you plan to do with the list.

Comment: I'm just learning website crawling. The problem i need to fix is to find emails from list of specific pages like contact us, about, help.

Comment: (re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", response.text) will this be a better regrex ?

Comment: Underscores and plusses are not permitted in the domain part.  The dot should not be backslashed inside a character class.  But yeah, that would fix the cases I identified off the top of my head.  There are corner cases like `" quoted string "@example.com` which are permitted by the RFC but not seen in practice really.

Comment: Oh okay. Let me give a try. Also can you help me on crawling the url on its specific page like contact us, help, about. I collected some of those keywords and have put them on a list. So before i start crawling, I wish to move to that right page and then start crawling the url to find the email.

Comment: The `[a-z]+` TLD will not work with [internationalized TLDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_country_code_top-level_domain), which contain dashes and potentially numbers also.

Comment: Oh.Thank you. I guess ^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$ can be used. Am not sure though..

Comment: That still doesn't cover IDNA TLDs though if you don't have any in your input, that's hardly a problem for you (and if you do, maybe they are human-readable, not in Punycode? Then your regex should be extended to something like `\.\pL+` at the end).

Comment: The terms you mentioned are new to me. I shall research on that and thank your suggestions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can access current url via `url` attribute of `response` object:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    url_keywords = ['stackoverflow', 'tea']

    def parse(self, response):
        story = FinaltestItem()
        # check if any of defined keywords can be found in response.url
        get_email = any(k in response.url for k in self.url_keywords)
        if get_email:  # if yes add in email!
            emails = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', response.body)
            story["email"] = emails
        story["url"] = response.url
        story["title"] = response.xpath("//title/text()").extract()
        return story
```

Comment: You mean, the "article_by_john" is the contact_page_pattern that I have to pass to the response object ?

Comment: @Niveram yes, see my edit on how you can implement simple version of this.

Comment: Thank you Granitosaurus. I can understand your comment. But I have a doubt, for example, if the url is www.abc.com, I need to append the url with the words in contact_page_pattern and for a url like www.abc.com/about and then search the email from that particular page.

Comment: `get_email = any(k in response.url for k in self.contact_page_pattern)
     print(get_email)`     When i print the get_email, it returns false and the email id not retrieved

Comment: Yes `get_email` is a boolean indicating whether to get email or not. If any of pattern bits are found in `response.url` then `get_email` becomes trues and email is added to item, however if no keywrods are found `get_email` is False and email is not being added.

Comment: Thank you Granitosaurus. I encounter some error which hinders me from the progress. I couldnt add my code here. Please suggest a way to share my code. The issue is it reaches the exact page but doesn't retrieves the email. Please share your contact, I have less reputation to contact you via stackoverlfow.